# Equivalence of regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions

Let $ A = \{a,b\}$ be an alphabet.
Please hint me with show, that this regexes are equivalent. 
That means, we should show that:
$L(e_1 )= L(e_2)$

1) $(a^*b)^*a^* = (a+b^*)^*$

2) $(a+b^*)^* = (a^*b^*)^*$

$+$ means or.

Comment: I don't think the regexes in (1) are equivalent: $(a*b)*$ matches a lone $b$ while the $(a+b*)*$ does not (I understand the $+$ as in egrep, that is, $a+$ is the same as $aa*$; if it means something different for you, please specify). The same is true for the second pair, where the right hand side matches a lone $b$ while the left hand side doesn't.

Comment: No, + means or.

Comment: Ah, OK, probably you should specify that in your question; I'm sure I'm not the only one who misunderstands it.

Comment: What is $e_1$ and $e_2$?

Comment: @mrp: Any two regular expressions whose equivalence is to be proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think that the simplest approach is probably to show that

$$L\big((a^*b)^*a^*\big)=L\big((a+b^*)^*\big)=L\big((a^*b^*)^*\big)=\{a,b\}^*\;,$$

i.e., that each of the three regular expressions is equivalent to $(a+b)^*$. This is especially easy with $(a+b^*)^*$. Clearly $L(a+b)\subseteq L(a+b^*)$, so $L\big((a+b)^*\big)\subseteq L\big((a+b^*)^*\big)$. On the other hand, $L\big(e)\subseteq L\big(a+b)^*\big)=\{a,b\}^*$ for every regular expression $e$ over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$, so $L\big(a+b^*)^*\big)=L\big((a+b)^*\big)$.

Similarly, $L(a+b)=L(a)\cup L(b)\subseteq L(a^*b^*)$, so ... ?

I’ll leave $(a^*b)^*a^*$ for you for now, but feel free to leave a question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks 
But I didn't deal with second. I suppose that I should show:
$(a^*b^*)^* \subset (a^*b)^*a^* $. Don't give me a solution. Give me a hint. :(

Comment: @user180834: That would be one way to do it, yes. I think, though, that I’d notice that $L(a+b)=L(a)\cup L(b)\subseteq L(a^*b)$, so $L\big((a+b)^*\big)\subseteq L\big((a^*b)^*\big)$ and then show that this is contained in ... ?

Comment: I am not sure, if it is true: $L(a+b)=L(a)\cup L(b)\subseteq L(a^*b)$
Why? $L(a) = \{a\}$ $L(b) = \{b\}$ and it's not true, that $\{ a \} \subset L(a^*b)$

Comment: @user180834: Oops. You’re right; I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote that. Your suggested approach probably is as easy as any. A genuine alternative is to start by showing that $L\big((a^*b)^*\big)=L\big((a+b)^*b\big)$.

Comment: yes. So 
$L\big((a^*b)^*\big)=L\big((a+b)^*b\big)$
and it's not true, that $L(a^*b)^* ) =L(a+b)^*$?

Comment: @user180834: Almost: I forgot about the empty word, so I should have written that $L\big((a^*b)^*\big)=\{\lambda\}\cup L\big((a+b)^*b\big)$: the non-empty members of $L\big((a^*b)^*\big)$ are the words that end with $b$. And that’s why $L\big((a^*b)^*\big)\ne L\big((a+b)^*\big)$.

Comment: @user180834: You’re welcome. I’m sorry about all of the mistakes; I seem to be having a bad day!